# Maven plugin - profileManager instance

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

How can I get a ProfileManager instance inside my mojo?
I'm trying to create a MavenProject using DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these two steps

**1)** Retrieve the MavenSession via injection

```
/**
 * The Maven Session
 *
 * @required
 * @readonly
 * @parameter
 * expression="${session}"
 */
private MavenSession session;
```

**2)** Use the session to get the Container and Execution Properties and Create a New ProfileManager

```
 PlexusContainer container = session.getContainer();  
 Properties execution = session.getExecutionProperties();
 ProfileManager manager = new DefaultProfileManager(container, execution);
```